# Is there any API to generate XSD programmatically?

Tags: xsd

Is there any APIs which I can use to create XSD programmatically? I have seen Membrane SOA API which looks pretty good, but they have not provided documentation for the API.

Is there any other API I can use to generate XSD?

Answer (score 0):

XSD is just XML with its own namespace. Any XML generation API (DOM or StAX) is fine. You could also use JAXB or XmlBeans to generate the code for [xsd schema (Click to download)](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd) itself and create schema in a type-safe manner.

If you are looking for XSD specific library then I suggest [Eclipse XSD library](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=xsd#xsd)